# can not import CursorResult from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, langchain

I am using langchain tool with streamlit and after running py file getting error that cannot import CursorResult from sqlalchemy

Comment: Please show us a [minimal reproducible example for your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`pip install -U sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 1):

Do pip install langchain==0.0.157
It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue happened because CursorResult was introduced in sqlalchemy 2, as mentioned in this PR: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/pull/4132